Optimal Game Strategy - Colored towers
What is the optimal strategy in the following $2$-player game?
The numbers $k,n$ are given, with $k<n$. The first player assigns one of $n$ possible colors to each cell in an $n$ by $n$ grid, with no repeated colors in any row or column (so each row and column is a permutation of the colors). Then, the second player chooses a set of $k$ colors that are worth points. In each column, the second player gets points for all the cells that lie in a "tower", a sequence of contiguous cells starting at the bottom and going upwards, all of which are in the set. So the tower grows upward until it reaches the first cell it finds that isn't in the set.
For example, in the game with $n=5$ and $k=3$, if the first player chooses a grid like this:
5 2 3 1 4
1 3 4 5 2
2 4 5 3 1
4 5 1 2 3
3 1 2 4 5

and then the second player chooses the set $\{2,3,4\}$, then the second player will get $7$ points for the $7$ cells that are not a dot:
. . . . .
. . . . .
2 . . 3 .
4 . . 2 .
3 . 2 4 .

Those are towers that start at the ground and rise as high as they can, but only including cells containing chosen colors. None of the towers in that picture can grow any taller, because each of them has a cell directly above it that contains a color that was not in the chosen set. From left to right, they are capped by $(1,1,1,5,5)$.
The first player tries to minimize the total points, and the second player tries to maximize. The game always lasts exactly two moves: color the grid, then choose the set of colors.
A possible strategy for the second player is to consider only $n$ possible sets, and choose the one with maximum points. Each set to consider is simply the bottom $k$ colors of a column. But it's not clear that that is optimal.
These are the values for the game for optimal play, for small $n$ and $k$, found by brute force exhaustive search:
        k
        1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
      _____________________
n  1 |  1
   2 |  1  4               
   3 |  1  3  9            
   4 |  1  3  6 16         
   5 |  1  3  5 10 25      
   6 |  1  3  5  8 15 36   
   7 |  1  3  5  8 12 21 49

What is the optimal strategy, in general?

Have you solved this for small values of $k,n$?  What is the value of the game for those values of $k,n$?

You gives values for optimal play. For each couple(k,n), you have only 1 value. How should we understand this ? I suppose that for any strategy for player 1, player 2 will always be able to obtain this optimal score ? In other Words, player 1 has no impact on final result. Or if player 1 can choose Good moves/Bad moves, it should be interesting to give more details.

For player $b$, this is the maximization of a supermodular function, which can be done in polynomial time. For $(3, 5)$, it's  possible to get 6 ($k$-th row is permutation $12345$ shifted by $k-1$)

In your example, the $3$ appears twice on the third row

For $(3, 5)$, we can even get $5$ with rows $34512;51234;45123;23451;12345$, which is optimal.

@caduk, can you expand on that? What is the supermodular function to be maximized? And what is the algorithm to do so?

The function maps the set chosen by $b$ to the points scored. The algorithms are quite complicated, you can search for submodular function minimization (which is equivalent)

Sorry, I may be wrong about the fact it is polynomial to optimize, because we have a constraint on the size of the subsets, which makes the maximization of submodular function NP-hard (though in this specific case, I don't know if this is NP-hard)

OK. Then it would be very interesting to know whether it's NP-hard, or polynomial, or something else. I wonder what can be proved here.

And it would be interesting whether an optimal first move can always consist of rows that are rotations of each other.
